# Passing JSON Error

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse JSON into some strings. Everything seems to be okay, but I am getting this same error. I hope to find help.

```
    {
  "response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "userTier": "developer",
    "total": 160689,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 1,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "pages": 160689,
    "orderBy": "newest",
    "results": [
      {
        "type": "article",
        "sectionId": "world",
        "webTitle": "Saudis lobby MEPs before arms embargo vote over Yemen",
        "webPublicationDate": "2016-02-25T06:01:25Z",
        "id": "world/2016/feb/25/saudis-lobby-meps-before-arms-embargo-vote-over-yemen",
        "fields": {
          "trailText": "Riyadh engaged in concerted effort to persuade European parliament not to pass amendment calling for EU sanctions because of bombing campaign",
          "thumbnail": "http://media.guim.co.uk/6646fa34096765c2e9456df41aa94d467cb22d7f/0_0_2835_1701/140.jpg"
        },
        "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/feb/25/saudis-lobby-meps-before-arms-embargo-vote-over-yemen",
        "sectionName": "World news"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here is my Parsing code:

```
    String title;
    String date;
    String text;
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    String webAddress;
    int dataSize;

    newsData = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject JSOnReceived = new JSONObject(JSON);
    JSONObject response = JSOnReceived.getJSONObject("response");
    String status = response.getString("status");
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
    {
        dataSize = response.getInt("pageSize");
        JSONArray results = response.getJSONArray("results");
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= dataSize)
        {
            JSONObject data = results.getJSONObject(i);
            title = data.getString("webTitle");
            Log.v("ARRAY TITLE", title + "DONE");
            date = data.getString("webPublicationDate");
            Log.v("ARRAY DATE", title + "DONE");

            JSONObject fields = data.getJSONObject("fields");
            text = fields.getString("trailText");
            Log.v("ARRAY TRAILTEXT", title + "DONE");
            String imageUrl = fields.getString("thumbnail");
            thumbnail = getImage(imageUrl);
            webAddress = data.getString("webUrl");
            newsData.add(new NewsFacade(title, date, text, thumbnail, webAddress));
            i++;
            Log.v("ARRAY DATA", title + "DONE");
```

But I'm getting this error from the JSONException that, "no value for field is found. I have changed it to Field, FIELD. But same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: instead of data size while loop use a for loop till array length

Comment: I have, but it didn't make a diffrence

Comment: is other fields of array are accessible?

Comment: In which iteration do you get the error? The first one or the second one?

Comment: Yes, I can access the webTitle and webPublicationDate strings. I just can't access the fileds object, so I cant accesss its memebrs. too.

Comment: I a having the error in the first iteration

Comment: In case you want to test it, you can make the call using this string  http://content.guardianapis.com/search?section=world&order-by=newest&use-date=published&show-fields=trailText%2Cthumbnail&page=1&page-size=1&api-key=test

Comment: I tested it on my side... It works fine for me...!!

Comment: You were able to parse it? Can I see how? I only need the field's properties to display in a TextView

Comment: See my answer. I could print the values in the logcat.

Comment: Are you sure, the response is coming true? Try printing each of the objects that you create. You might find some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop may execute one more time than the actual length. Change the while loop condition to following :

```
i < results.length().
```

It may help you.

Comment: I have done that, same error. I have even given it a harcoded value, still same error. I don't think the error has to do with the loop. It would have being OutOfArrayIndexException rather, "VALUE FOR FIELDS NOT FOUND"

Comment: Problem may be occuring here: "id": "world/2016/feb/25/saudis-lobby-meps-before-arms-embargo-vote-over-yemen". Can you try avoiding the slash while sending the json response?

Comment: Why should it be a problem, please explain

Comment: I am not sending the JSON, I am receiving it from a public API, and parsing it to display a newsfeed.

Comment: Sorry. The response is valid. There is no problem with the slashes. I am trying to figuring out the problem.

Comment: In case you want to test it properly, you might need the make the call yourself, here is the http string.   http://content.guardianapis.com/search?section=world&order-by=newest&use-date=published&show-fields=trailText%2Cthumbnail&page=1&page-size=1&api-key=test

Comment: I parsed the response in the same way you parsed it. But no problem occurred.

Comment: Is fixed, you can check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried parsing just the `result` part and it works:

```
String test = "{\"results\": [{ \"fields\": {\"trailText\": \"Riyadh engaged i because of bombing campaign \",\"thumbnail\": \"http://media.guim.co.uk/6646fa34096765c2e945f/0_0_2835_1701/140.jpg\"},\"webUrl\": \"http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/feb/25/saudis-lobby-meps-before-arms-embargo-vote-over-yemen\"}    ]}";

        try {
            JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject(test);
            JSONArray arrayJSON = testJson.getJSONArray("results");
            JSONObject obj1 = arrayJSON.getJSONObject(0);
            Log.i("JSON", obj1.toString());
            JSONObject test1 = obj1.getJSONObject("fields");
            Log.i("FIELDS", test1.toString());
            String tmp = test1.getString("trailText");
            Log.i("FIELDS", tmp);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I just realized, I am not recieing the fields object at all. But what could be the problem?

Comment: What do you get in `JSOnReceived` ? Can you  add its output in the question?

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot even make your answer as an "Answer". I was told I need a reputation of 15. I hope thank you will be enough. My data is showing now!!! Thank you

Comment: It's fixed, instead of a simple comma, in the addQueryWithParameter method, I using this "%2C" instead. So it was ignoring my fields query

Comment: Happy to help ... :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
final String baseUri = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?";
        Uri uriBuilder = Uri.parse(baseUri)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("section", "world")
                .appendQueryParameter("order-by", "newest")
                .appendQueryParameter("use-date", "published")
                .appendQueryParameter("show-fields", "trailText,thumbnail")
                .appendQueryParameter("page", "1")
                .appendQueryParameter("page-size", "1")
                .appendQueryParameter("api-key", "test")
                .build();
```

I was doing this:
    .appendQueryParameter("show-fields", "trailText%2Cthumbnail").

And the server was ignoring that part of the query.